# Is it possible to "program" a command wrapper?

Tags: macros

I have the following doubt: *Is it ever possible to define a command that takes a word as an argument and executes the command with that same name?*

For instance, something like

```
\newcommand{\wrapper}[1]{%
    \@nameuse{#1}%
}
```

in such a way calling `\wrapper{hrule}` gets converted into `\hrule`.

**Motivation**

The main objective I have with this is to "assign" values to previously defined commands, as I load its values via a CSV file using `datatools`:

`\assignto{somevar}{value}` --> `\renewcommand{\somevar}{value}`

`\assignto{othervar}{command}` --> `\renewcommand{\othervar}{\command}`

This code snippet was the first idea I had, but it doesn't work.

```
\newcommand{\assignto}[2]{%
    \@ifundefined{#2}{%
        \renewcommand{\@nameuse{#1}}{#2}%
    }{%
        \renewcommand{\@nameuse{#1}}{\@nameuse{#2}}%
    }%
}
```

*Sample error output:*

```
! LaTeX Error: \@nameuse {unidad} undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Comment: Something like this: `\newcommand\cmdmaker[2]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{\textbf{#2}}}`? Usage: `\cmdmaker{somevar}{value}`.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that you should give your automatically created macros some "namespace". Imagine someone writes `\wrapper{def}{ghi}`. This is guaranteed to break LaTeX with your idea (and with Werner's solution as well).

Comment: @yo' For example, putting them a prefix? If I write `\wrapper{def}{ghi}`, both the command and the value can have, I don't know, `int_` as prefix to differentiate them among other valid `TeX` names.

Comment: @logo_writer Exactly like that. I would recommend sticking to LaTeX2e standard and use `@` in the name, something like `logodata@#1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to your first question comes from the LaTeX kernel, which provides `\@namedef` specifically for this reason. Therefore, in your preamble you can use

```
\makeatletter
\let\wrapper\@namedef
\makeatother
```

and then use

```
\wrapper{abc}{def}% --> \def\abc{def}
```

Your use of `\assignto` seems different though, as it should convert the second argument to either a value (which may be text), or to a command. For this one could use some e-TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\assignto}[2]{%
  \ifcsname #2\endcsname
    \@namedef{#1}{\csname #2\endcsname}%
  \else
    \@namedef{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\abc}{ABC}

\assignto{AAA}{aaa}\AAA

\assignto{BBB}{abc}\BBB

\end{document}
```

To use a more LaTeX-like approach, you can use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) which provides a host of wrapper macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\assignto}[2]{%
  \ifcsdef{#2}{%
    \csdef{#1}{\csuse{#2}}%
  }{%
    \csdef{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\abc}{ABC}

\assignto{AAA}{aaa}\AAA

\assignto{BBB}{abc}\BBB

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE works flawlessly! Thanks! It was the idea I had in mind! When I want to use it with `datatool` it loads data strangely as if it read the *last* value, though, as I iterate through the DB. Nonetheless, this basically works with "hardcoded" data, so I'm accepting this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using the same interface for two distinct jobs. In your proposed syntax, `\assignto{\foo}{text}` would see that `\text` is defined (assuming you load `amsmath`) and you *don't* want that `\foo` expands to some mysterious value, do you?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\assignto{\@ifstar\assignto@expand\assignto@simple}
\newcommand{\assignto@simple}[2]{\@namedef{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\assignto@expand}[2]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\assignto@expand@aux
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{#1}}
\newcommand\assignto@expand@aux[2]{\assignto@simple{#2}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\abc}{ABC}

\assignto{AAA}{aaa}\AAA

\assignto{BBB}{abc}\BBB

\assignto*{CCC}{abc}\CCC

\end{document}
```

Now you have no ambiguity in what `abc` should mean.

Comment: I see, with this I can choose whether to expand the value assigned or not. Nice!