# Using "datatool" to assign values to newly created commands ends filling all with the last value

Tags: datatool, csv

I'm trying to create new commands by taking their values via a CSV file and `datatool` to load them into a DB. The problem is that every created command with this process ends with the values assigned to the *last* entry in the DB.

**MWE**

Here I put both the CSV used and a MWE (thanks to Werner for the "command wrapper", whereabouts [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268638/is-it-possible-to-program-a-command-wrapper)):

The CSV file:

```
Campo,Valor,Aux
hallo,"Cmon",
another,"Piece",
whuzzat,"abc",
```

The `LaTeX` document used to load the CSV file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\assignto}[2]{%
    \ifcsdef{#2}{%
        \csdef{#1}{\csuse{#2}}%
    }{%
        \csdef{#1}{#2}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \section*{Hard-coded variables}

    \newcommand{\abc}{ABC}
    \assignto{AAA}{aaa}\AAA\ %end to denote space
    \assignto{BBB}{abc}\BBB

    \section*{DB variables}

    \DTLloaddb{Datos}{datos.csv}
    \DTLforeach{Datos}{\campo=Campo,\valor=Valor,\valorb=Aux}{%
        \assignto{\campo}{\valor}
    }

    \hallo\ % It should be "Cmon"
    \another\ % It should be "Piece"
    \whuzzat\ % It should be "\abc", i.e. "ABC"
\end{document}
```

*Output:*

[image: Result when compiling this MWE]

Comment: You need to expand the valor e.g. with `\csedef`, but I do find your code highly dangerous. You are creating commands without checking if you are overwriting existing commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, it was just for the sake of the example. I was already told that using prefixes (namespacing them) should be taken into account to avoid such editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically doing

```
\def\hallo{\valor}
```

and you should expand `\valor` before doing the definition:

```
\DTLforeach{Datos}{\campo=Campo,\valor=Valor,\valorb=Aux}{%
    \expandafter\assignto\expandafter{\expandafter\campo\expandafter}\expandafter{\valor}
}
```

Of course there are better and shorter ways; for instance

```
\newcommand\assignto[2]{\expandafter\assigntoaux\expandafter{#2}{#1}}
\newcommand{\assigntoaux}[2]{%
  \ifcsdef{#1}{%
    \csdef{#2}{\csuse{#1}}%
  }{%
    \csdef{#2}{#1}%
   }%
}
```

just switching the arguments.

An even better way is with `xparse` and `expl3`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Campo,Valor,Aux
hallo,"Cmon",
another,"Piece",
whuzzat,"abc",
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\assignto}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \logowriter_assignto:no { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \logowriter_assignto:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \logowriter_assignto:nn
 {
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \logowriter_assignto:nn { no }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section*{Hard-coded variables}

\newcommand{\abc}{ABC}
\assignto{AAA}{aaa}\AAA\ %end to denote space
\assignto{BBB}{abc}\BBB

\section*{DB variables}

\DTLloaddb{Datos}{\jobname.csv}
\DTLforeach{Datos}{\campo=Campo,\valor=Valor,\valorb=Aux}{%
  \assignto*{\campo}{\valor}
}

\hallo\ % It should be "Cmon"
\another\ % It should be "Piece"
\whuzzat\ % It should be "\abc", i.e. "ABC"

\end{document}
```

Note that `\assignto*` expands once the second argument, before doing the definition, which is the same as the long chain of `\expandafter` tokens above, but much simpler.

[image]

Comment: Wow, you're pretty fast! Thanks, I've tested it and works! One question, though: Does `expandafter` gets the value of the command *before* or *after* processing the line?

Comment: @logo_writer *When* expanding `\assignto`. It does nothing at definition time, it just gets stored.

Comment: So that's why the value is lost when not expanding. Pretty impressive that there are plenty of options, though. Why did you switch the arguments in the second solution?

Comment: @logo_writer Just to use less `\expandafter`'s

Comment: Thanks! If I have two normal values instead, how do I expand them with `expandafter`? That is, suppose the second command is not a command by itself, but just like #2 in this example.

Comment: @logo_writer That's why I presented the simpler solution with `expl3`